# Android: Passing text through Regex method, and displaying on EditText

Tags: java, android, regex, android-intent, android-edittext

I am trying to pass a text output into a regex method whereby I can take this entire text output and extract out the email address.

For example, I have the text output below:

```
Genos Taper
Assitant Manager

90606968
genostaper@hotmail.com
```

I want to pass the above text output into the regex method and extract out "genostaper@hotmail.com" and display into an EditText.

Below are my codes:

```
public class CreateContactActivityOCRtest extends Activity {

private String recognizedText, textToUse;
private EditText mEditText1, mEditText2;
private String mFromLang, mCurrentLang;

private Pattern pattern;
private Matcher matcher;

private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN =
        "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_createcontact);

    // Getting the path of the image to show
    Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    recognizedText = extras.getString("TEXT");
    textToUse = recognizedText;

    // Getting the language used for text recognition
    mFromLang = extras.getString("LANG");
    mCurrentLang = mFromLang;
    //Log.i(TAG, mFromLang);

    textToUse = EmailValidator();
    setupUI();
}

public String EmailValidator() {

    String email = textToUse;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        return email.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());

    } else {
        // TODO handle condition when input doesn't have an email address
    }

    return email;

}

public boolean validate(final String hex) {

    matcher = pattern.matcher(hex);
    return matcher.matches();

}

public void setupUI(){

    // Setting up the textbox

    mEditText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EmailET);
    mEditText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.role);
    mEditText1.setText(textToUse);
    mEditText2.setText(textToUse);

}
```

}

What I am trying to do is:

1. Receive the text output from another class (**Already done**)
2. Pass Entire Text Output into `EmailValidator()` (**Not sure if I did it correctly**)
3. Take the output from `EmailValidator()` and pass it to `setupUI()` (**Not done**)

Where did it went wrong? The passing of the text output, or the regex method? Any ideas please provide. Thanks~~

Answer (score 1):

you are not assigning the returning value to textToUse

```
textToUse= EmailValidator();
```

Comment: Where should I place this line? Inside EmailValidator() method?